# Missing required parameter for [Route: xxxxx]

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-9

I am having this route setup on my laravel app which uses the `FooController` which uses an `__invoke` method

```
Route::get('/foos/{foo:baz_param}', FooController::class)->name('foos');
```

I am also having a link in my blade template which is this

```
<a href="{{ route('foos', ['baz_param' => $foo->baz_param]) }}">
     {{ $foo->baz_param }}
</a>
```

however I am getting the following error on screen

```
Missing required parameter for [Route: foos] [URI: foos/{foo}] [Missing parameter: foo].
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based what error says, it expects parameter name as `foo`. So yon can modify your key name to match parameter name.

```
<a href="{{ route('foos', ['foo' => $foo->baz_param]) }}">
```

Or modify your Route parameter name to match the key in link.

```
Route::get('/foos/{baz_param}', ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work aswell as long as $foo contains a variable baz_param:

```
<a href="{{ route('foos', $foo) }}">
   {{ $foo->baz_param }}
</a>
```